# Gateway not reachable for PowerLine AV Wireless N Extender

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have added a D-Link PowerLine AV Wireless N Extender (DHP-W306AV) to my existing power line network.

The router is added as 192.168.0.50 and can be accessed both from my main PC (using the power line LAN) as well as a netbook that uses the wireless network (called home1) configured on the D-Link device.

The problem is that the netbook cannot access the internet via home1. The error message (when asking to Diagnose the issue) is: 'The default gateway is not available'.

It appears that something is misconfigured in the D-Link device (acting as router/gateway for the home1 wireless network).

**EDIT:**
In the LAN setup page is specified the following:

```
   My LAN Connection is: Static IP     (the other option is DHCP)
             IP Address: 192.168.0.50
            Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (same as main network)
        Gateway Address: 192.168.0.1   (DSL Modem and DHCP host)
```

I don't see any option to disable the NAT nor any way to create a different subnet (or do I simply change the mask?).

Any suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue?

Comment: I take back my previous Answer. It looks like your device is just a bridge, not a NAT gateway, so it wasn't the problem I thought it was (same subnet on both sides of a NAT gateway).

Comment: When I change the Subnet Mask to 255.255.0.0 it seems to work, but then when I turn the device off and on again it keeps the setting, but the internet connection is again missing.